# How to send data to controller from view cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

How to send hidden or encrypted data to controller from view?

i have an user_id with company_id to send to controller from view through

a link eg:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link(
    $user['Recruiter']['title'],
    array(
        'controller'=>'users',
        'action'=>'action/'.$user['Recruiter']['id'].'/'.$user['Recruiter']['title']
    ),
    array(
        'escape'=>false
    )
);
?>
```

Comment: As asked that doesn't make much sense - what info in the above example is to be hidden/encrypted?

Comment: A form? POST? GET parameters on a link?

Comment: [HTML Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-libraries/helpers/html.html).  By cake convention your url array need to be formated like this : `array('controller' => 'controller_name', 'action' => 'action_name', parameter1, parameter2, ...)`  but the question is what do ypu want after ? a redirection, that nothing happen, ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link(
    $user['Recruiter']['title'],
    array(
        'controller'=>'users',
        'action'=>'action',
        $user['Recruiter']['id'],
        $user['Recruiter']['title']
    ),
    array(
        'escape'=>false
    )
);
?>
```

You have to get id and title in user controller like

```
function action($id=null,$title=null)
{
  ...
}
```